# Call a function on a click with ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Simple question !

I have this function in my JS file

```
function getdata()
{
    Ext.Ajax.request(
    {
        url: '/app_dev.php/getdata',
        success: function (response)
        {
            console.log('réponse' + response.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (response, opts)
        {
            console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
        }
    });
}
```

and then a menu with a listeners

```
menu: [
    {
        text: 'Import'
    },
    {
        text: 'Consultation',
        listeners:
        {
            click: function (getdata) {}
        },
```

Not working :(. 
 How can I call the function with clicking on the menu button ?
Please, I am aware this question is noob but **don't put me some -1** :-).
From a guy trying to learn javascript !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it now `getdata` is just a parameter to the click handler and not the function you want calling.

You need to change it to something like this:

```
listeners: {
    click: function() { 
        getdata();
    }                                     
}
```

Or better yet:

```
listeners: {
    click: getdata                                    
}
```

Comment: Thanks you :) and excuse my newbness